# OpenGL: Sphere texture appearing oddly

Tags: c, opengl

I'm currently trying to map this pool ball texture to a sphere I have created. My approach is as follows:

1. Generate the sphere vertices
2. For every sphere vertex, translate that vertexes coordinates from the openGL world to the texture coordinates.

I want the white circle with the '1' in it to appear at the top of the sphere (at z=1), so I am using the x and z coordinates of the sphere vertices.

The texture file I am using has multiple textures. The texture below is the one I am concerned with. In the texture file, the top left of this particular texture is at (0.01, 0.01) and the bottom right is at (0.24, 0.24). If my math is right, this makes the dead center at about (0.115, 0.115). Since I want the white circle to be on top of the ball (z=1), I've come up with the following two lines of code to map the points:

```
tex_coords[i].x = 0.125 + (verticies[i].x)*0.115;
tex_coords[i].y = 0.125 + (verticies[i].z)*0.115;
```

My logic is that if X or Z is 0, the respective coordinate is 0.115, which is right in the middle. Otherwise, X and Z range from -1 to 1 so the maximum value we can reach is 0.24 and the minimum value is 0.01.

As you can see in the bottom screenshot, something has gone wrong. If you look very closely you can see that one tiny part of the sphere is colored white.

[image: This is the texture I am trying to use]

[image: This is what is appearing]

Comment: You asked and deleted the exact same question yesterday. What has changed now?

Comment: if `vertices` are the sphere mesh vertexes then you need to convert them [from cartesian into spherical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) first (which I do not see anywhere in your posted code, also do not forget to take in mind what is the center of your sphere ...) and then convert the resulting `lat,long` angles into your texture range ... Much easier/faster is to precompute the coordinates on CPU side before passing into VBO ...

Answer (score -1):

There was a discrepancy between one of my shaders and my init function. I had a variable called "vTexCoord" in my shaders but was using "vTexCoords" in my init function.